# How to copy files to a list of remote machines simultaneously?

Tags: shell, vbscript, xcopy

I have a VBScript function that copies files to remote machines using the xcopy command. The script first reads the list of target machines from a text file, converts the list to an array and then loops through the array. For each target machine in the array, I use xcopy to transfer the specified files there.
This system works fine but since I have over 40 target machines, it takes a while to complete. Is there a quicker way to do this? Is there a way to perform a "broadcast" copy files to all machines at once?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBScript you can only do this sequentially, because the language/interpreter doesn't support parallel processing. You may be able to do it with a batch script, though:

```
for /f %%h in (targets.txt) do (
  start "" "%COMSPEC%" /c xcopy C:\src \\%%h\dst
)
```

Note that this won't necessarily speed things up, since bandwidth is a limited resource that is shared by all tasks. When running several tasks in parallel each task will have just a fraction of the bandwidth and will thus take longer to complete.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. Since there's no obvious solution, I'll leave it as it is. Thanks, John